pnpm command not found when running with script using github actions but worked when run it manually on server
I am trying to automate my Next.js deployment and write a deploy.sh script to run on the server using GitHub Actions. I tried running it manully on server using bash deploy.sh command and it works fine but when I run it through GitHub Actions it says:
err: .scripts/deploy.sh: line 14: npm: command not found

This is my main.yaml file:
name: main

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
          script: "cd ~/gempad-Interface && bash .scripts/deploy.sh"

This is my deploy.sh file:
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Deployment started..."

expect <<EOF
spawn git pull origin main
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/***/.ssh/id_ed25519':"
send "password\n"
expect eof
EOF
echo "New changes copied to server !"

echo "Installing Dependencies..."
pnpm install 

echo "Creating Production Build..."
pnpm run build

echo "PM2 Reload"
pm2 reload gemlaunch-interface

echo "Deployment Finished!"


I got it solved by adding this in my script before installing dependencies.
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

here is my updated deploy.sh file
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Deployment started..."

expect <<EOF
spawn git pull origin main
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/***/.ssh/id_ed25519':"
send "password\n"
expect eof
EOF
echo "New changes copied to server !"

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

echo "Installing Dependencies..."
pnpm install 

echo "Creating Production Build..."
pnpm run build

echo "PM2 Reload"
pm2 reload gemlaunch-interface

echo "Deployment Finished!"

